# Regular Expression in a METAR

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have some kind of simple and tricky problem.
Here I have a METAR (Weather in a very specific string format).

```
LIEA 051550Z 21005KT 9999 FEW020 19/14 Q1011
```

In this string, 051550Z represents that the weather bullettin has been emitted on 5th of the month at 15:50 UTC,... and 9999 indicates the visibility,...

Well, I tried to match a RegExp which could output me the visibility, but I didn't manage to get out of the problem.

preg_match_all() returns me the numbers

```
0515 (from the time group)
2100 (from the wind group)
9999 (wanted)
1011 (from the pressure group)
```

with the RegExp I've tried

```
([0-9]{4})
```

And then, I blindly added a

```
(?!Z)
```

trying not to get at least the time group...
But it doesn't work...

Looking at the problem itself, is it better to consider taking every time the third element of the array (without (?!Z) RegExp addition) or trying to catch directly the right value?
In my opinion the last choice would be better...
So, how can I get the visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` and then match 4 digits to get the visibility:

```
\b\d{4}\b
```

If it has to be 4 digits at the fourth position you could also match the first 3 sets matching 1+ times not a whitespace character `\S+` followed by 1+ times a horizonal whitespace `\h` and repeat that 3 times.

Then use `\K` to forget what was matched and match 4 digit followed by a word boundary.

`^(?:\S+\h+){3}\K\d{4}\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eqvbKV/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me.